# log4j.properties not picked up from jar

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a jar in the classpath of my server which contains the log4j.properties file on root of the jar for logging of the code. When the code in the jar runs the logging for the code is not occuring. When I analyzed the problem using **java -Dlog4j.debug** option I got to know that the log4j is loading the log4j.properties file of **axis-ant.jar** (this also is on my classpath) and using it instead of my jar's property file.

When i subsequently removed the axis-ant.jar from the classpath my jars log4j.properties file was picked immediately and logging for my code occured.

**Can somebody please explain why is my log4j.properties fle not being loaded while axis-ant.jar is present?**

Surprisingly the same jar with axis-ant.jar present in classpath is running with proper logging successfully in another server.. both the server have the same java 5 version installed and same version of log4j jar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at the [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) manual. The section "Default Initialization Procedure" describes how log4j will try to find the initialization file and explains possibilities to match a special configuration (e.g. by setting the system property `log4j.configuration`).

If you do not want to do any special configuration you have to ensure that your configuration file will be the first one found on the classpath.

Comment: +1 for the manual and the correct section :)  One quote from that page: "The preferred way to specify the default initialization file is through the log4j.configuration system property." So should one want to load a specific file, give that one a special name and pass it to the log4j.configuration system property.

Comment: the solution seems to be keeping one single file for all the logging. This needs to be kept at a location acessible to log4j.. Thanks

Comment: By setting `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties` in my tomcat startup, my web application started using `$CATALINA/lib/log4j.properties` instead of the embedded jar files log4j configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The properties file is picked up from the jar based on the order in which the jar is found in classpath by your application server. Now there is no way to conclusively tell the  jar from which the properties file is to be loaded.

To get around this problem most projects **include your log4j.properties file in the server classpath itself**. This way this file is the first properties file to be loaded and this is the one which your logging code gets.

Comment: So we are saying that we should ideally have a single log4j.properties for a project and keep the same in the classpath.

Comment: Yes. You really do not need multiple log4j.properties files. You can just add whatever rules you want in a single one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note quite sure but it could be an order problem. Whichever log4j.properties is loaded first/last would win (I'd have to check that).

Comment: If log4j is loading property files in order then it implies the first loaded log4j.properties file will always supersede all the the other log4j.properties in classpath. This will be a logging nightmare in case when the log4j.properies for multiple jars is supposed to be loaded

Comment: Well, how should one handle contradicting properties? The easiest way would be not to allow that by just using one file (first or last is irrelevant in this case).

Comment: yeah keeping a single file seems to be the solution .. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because axis-ant.jar comes before in classpath the your own jar. I assume putting your jar before in classpath then axis-ant.jar should help

Comment: ok ... but in my case the axis-ant.jar is put in ext folder. Could this be the reason its getting loaded first?

Comment: yes..all jars in the ext(extension dir) folder will be picked up before the jars in the class path, because ext jars are loaded by extension classloader which is the parent for application class loader