# Specifying log4j.xml as a file

Tags: java, jar, log4j

When i specified the path of the file, i.e `file:///sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml` (this is not in a jar), its not taking `log4j.xml` from that path, instead it's taking the default `log4j.xml` stored in a jar.

How can i specify that path so that it takes `log4j.xml` from the specified path, instead taking it from a jar?

Comment: Where do you specify that path?

Comment: In the code of classpathresource

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Log4J Default Initialization procedure. I did an answer on this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402953/log4j-properties-not-picked-up-from-jar/5403087#5403087).

Comment: Adding code examples will help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("file:///sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml");
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```

Comment: will this work ?? ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("file:/sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml");

Comment: I used FileSystemResource.when i used classpathresource it was searching in that class path only.But it was not there in that class path.I used FileSystemResource and this will search the entire file system..thank you all....

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/user/path/to/your/log4j.xml -jar yourJar.jar
```